# Grab only certain records on JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I need to work out how to grab only certain records of the json object below. For instance only ones whos name is Spain.

I've done some research but nothing I have read makes much sense to me.

```
var trips = [
 {
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Barcelona",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },{
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 2,
   "city": "Moraira",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Portugal",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Lisbon",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Italy",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Rome",
   "year": 2017,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "France",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Paris",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 }
]
```

The intention is to be able to loop through the records and display only the ones referring to certain countries. I hope this is specific enough of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the original array using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var trips = [
 {
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Barcelona",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },{
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 2,
   "city": "Moraira",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Portugal",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Lisbon",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Italy",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Rome",
   "year": 2017,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "France",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Paris",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 }
]    
    
var filtered = trips.filter(function(val){
  return val.name == 'Spain';
})

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const trips = [
 {
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Barcelona",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },{
   "name": "Spain",
   "visit_id": 2,
   "city": "Moraira",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Portugal",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Lisbon",
   "year": 2016,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "Italy",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Rome",
   "year": 2017,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 },
 {
   "name": "France",
   "visit_id": 1,
   "city": "Paris",
   "year": 2015,
   "main_img": "main.jpg",
   "other_imgs": "001.jpg, 002.jpg"
 }
];

const result = trips.filter(el => el.name === 'Spain');

console.log(result);
```

Anyway, this solution won't work in some older versions of browsers because it is using `filter` and fat arrows (`=>`) that are ECMAScript2015 (ES6) features.